# Lightning Experience: why can't we use Standard Lightning Tabs Component on Non-Record Flexipages?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience

On record pages (e.g. Flexipages for the Account record or for an Custom Object) we can use the Standard Tabs Component like this:

[image]

Why are we not allowed to use them on non-record homepages? The Tabs Component simply does not show up in the left panel at "Standard". Is this a bug or a feature on purpose? If on purpose, I can't understand the reason behind this limitation, since especially on a homepage the use of tabs would make perfectly make sense to avoid unnecessary scroll-tapestries.

Or do I miss something to make them show up in the designer?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm the PM for App Builder, thanks for the feedback. We are assessing how to make this happen for all page types, including those that are mobile friendly. It won't show up in the next release, but it's on our nearer term roadmap (safe harbor). If you add it to our IdeaExchange, you can track the progress and gain support from other users to help us drive the priority higher: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaSearch.